# Cricles not showing in TikzPicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I'm using a pgfplotssetup for my document in order to draw 3d plots, and an axis setup for my 2d plot. Every plot or draw are shown in the document except for circles (both draw or fill) and I don't understand what causes the problem because the setups i found online are quit big. Here the code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\axisdefaultwidth{360pt}
\pgfplotsset{
legend pos=outer north east,
    legend style={
      draw=none,
      fill opacity=0.75,
      fill=text!6!page,
      text opacity=1
    },
    legend cell align={left},
    % -- AXIS
    axis lines=middle,
    axis on top,
    % -- AXIS ARROWS
    inner axis line style={draw=none},
    clip mode=individual,
    every axis/.append style = {thick},tick style = {thick,black},
    %
    % #1 = x, y, or z
    % #2 = the shift value
    /tikz/normal shift/.code 2 args = {%
        \pgftransformshift{%
            \pgfpointscale{#2}{\pgfplotspointouternormalvectorofticklabelaxis{#1}}%
        }%
    },%
    %
    range3frame/.style = {
        tick align        = outside,
        scaled ticks      = false,
        enlargelimits     = false,
        ticklabel shift   = {10pt},
        axis lines*       = left,
        line cap          = round,
        clip              = false,
        xtick style       = {normal shift={x}{10pt}},
        ytick style       = {normal shift={y}{10pt}},
        ztick style       = {normal shift={z}{10pt}},
        x axis line style = {normal shift={x}{10pt}},
        y axis line style = {normal shift={y}{10pt}},
        z axis line style = {normal shift={z}{10pt}},
    },
        % % -- TICKS
    minor x tick num=1,
    % xtick pos=left,
    % ytick pos=left,
    enlarge x limits=false,
    every x tick/.style={color=text, thin},
    every y tick/.style={color=text, thin},
    tick align=outside,
    % xtick placement tolerance=-1mm,
    % ytick placement tolerance=-1mm,
    % -- LABELS
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    every tick label/.append style={font=\fontfamily{\headingsFont}\selectfont},
    xlabel near ticks,
    ylabel near ticks,
    % -- COLOURS / STYLES
    cycle multi list={solid,{dotted,mark options={solid}},{dashed,mark options={solid}}\nextlist quaternary,secondary,primary,tertiary},
    %
    every axis plot/.append style={
      very thick,
      line cap=round
    },
    samples=100,
    enlargelimits={abs=1pt}, % prevent clipping of plot lines
    % inner axis line style={shorten >=0.6pt, shorten <=0.6pt},
    % -- ASYMPTOTES
    asym gap/.initial=0.02,
    v asym/.style={unbounded coords=jump,
      /utils/exec={\foreach \aympX [count=\asympcount] in {#1} {
          \ifnum\asympcount=1
          \xdef\bmc@plotasymfilter{abs(x-\aympX)<\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/asym gap}}
          \else
          \xdef\bmc@plotasymfilter{\bmc@plotasymfilter || abs(x-\aympX)<\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/asym gap}}
          \fi}},
      y filter/.expression = {\bmc@plotasymfilter ? inf:y},
      execute at end plot visualization={
        \begin{scope}
          \clip (rel axis cs:0,0) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,1);
          \foreach \aympX in {#1}
          {\draw[current plot style,densely dashed,thin]
            ({rel axis cs:0,0} -| {axis cs:\aympX,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,1} -| {axis cs:\aympX,0});}
        \end{scope}
      }
    },
    h asym/.style={unbounded coords=jump,
      execute at end plot visualization/.append={
        \begin{scope}
          \clip (rel axis cs:0,0) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,1);
          \draw[current plot style,densely dashed,thin]
          ({rel axis cs:0,0} |- {axis cs:0,#1}) -- ({rel axis cs:1,0} |- {axis cs:0,#1});
        \end{scope}
      }
    }
}

\begin{document}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[%grid=both, grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
            axis equal image, minor tick num=0,
            enlargelimits={abs=0.5}, ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
            xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
            ymin=-2,
            ymax=2,
            xmin=-2,
            xmax=2,
            xstep=0.5,ystep=0.5, 
            xtick={-3,...,1.5},ytick={-3,...,1.5},
            axis lines = middle,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
            axis line style={draw},
               ]
                    \fill[color=black!15] (axis cs: 0, 0) circle [radius=2];
                    \fill[color=blue!25] (axis cs: 1, 1.7) circle [radius=0.5];
                    \node at (axis cs:0.5,0.5) {\small $E$};
                    \filldraw[blue] (axis cs:1,1.7) circle (1pt) node[anchor=west]{\small $b\notin E$};
                    \addplot[blue, domain=-1:1]{3*sin(deg(x))};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your example code is not working. Please turn it into a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: The radius is so small that the circles are not visible because of the lines over them. Try `[radius=5]` or `[radius=2pt]`.

Comment: @dexteritas you are right, with a previous version of the code without the pfgplotssetup ``[radius=2]`` worked, but now I just had to make it way bigger. Thanks a lot